# How to keep all selected days after clicking on a selected day?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I found in full calendar documentation:
*"A selection might be cleared for a number of reasons:
1.The user clicks away from the current selection (doesn't happen when unselectAuto is false)."*
But if I have selected more days, click in the current selection will also unselect existing selection.
Actually, I am trying to achieve the following:
1)User selects a few days on the month view 
2)than he clicks somewhere in the selected area
3)Calendar is keeping selected days

I've tried something with option unselectCancel:".fc-cell-overlay" but it doesn't work

Any advice is much appreciated
Regards, Niki

Comment: are you using datepicker? from jquery ui?

Comment: I'm using jquery Full Calendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/